# Word Cloud in R Shiny Dashboard showing up in viewing pane instead of app window

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to create a wordcloud in Shiny Dashboard. The radio button controls and all the other things are working fine except the output for wordcloud is being shown in the viewing pane inside R Studio and not in the shiny app.

Pretty new to Shiny programming and have tried using both renderPlot and reactivePlot in server.R

Would anyone know why?

Here is the snapshot of my code

```
                shinyUI(dashboardPage(

              # DASHBOARD HEADER
              dashboardHeader(title = "ABC Classification"),

              # DASHBOARD SIDEBAR
              dashboardSidebar(
                sidebarMenu(
                  menuItem("Word Cloud", tabName = "wordcloud")
                )
            ),

            dashboardBody(
                  tabItems(
                    tabItem(tabName = "wordcloud",
                      fluidRow(
                        box(title = "Select option", radioButtons("radio_buttons", "A", "B", "C" choices = c("A", "B", "C"))),
                        box(title = " Word Cloud ", plotOutput("word_cloud"))
                        )
                    )
                )
            )




            shinyServer(function(input, output) {
              output$word_cloud = renderPlot(
                if (input$radio_buttons == "A"){
                  wordcloud2(cloud_a)
                }else if (input$radio_buttons == "B"){
                  wordcloud2(cloud_b)
                }else if (input$radio_buttons == "C"){
                    wordcloud2(cloud_c)
                }
                )  
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please share your `cloud_a` etc data so we can reproduce your example. I am taking an example from the help pages now.

Your only mistake is that you should use `wordcloud2Output` instead of `plotOutput` and `renderWordcloud2` instead of `renderPlot`. With this it works fine. Minimal example:

```
library(wordcloud2)
shinyApp(shinyUI(
  fluidPage(wordcloud2Output("word_cloud"))),
  shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$word_cloud = renderWordcloud2({
      wordcloud2(demoFreq)
    })
  })
)
```

Thanks for pointing to the package, I didn't know about it but I like it!

[image]

Comment: @shoeaco Many thanks for reviewing the code and pointing out the errors.

Comment: Many thanks for reviewing the code and pointing out the errors.

1. Using ``library(wordcloud2)`` - details here [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-wordcloud2-library/)
2. function ``wordcloud2`` is part of the above library
3.data ``cloud_a`` is a cloud which is working fine in global.R and otherwise if I run it outside of the Shiny app

The main issue is the word cloud is getting displayed in the viewing pane section of Rstudio while everything else is running fine within the Shiny dashboard

Comment: Thanks for your information :) I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Excellent!! Many thanks for your help. You saved my day.. just in time :) All working fine now and learnt from my mistake.